# ORDS 18.4 Why am I getting an empty :body_text (CLOB)?

Tags: rest, oracle-apex

Tell me, please, why does the empty value come?
To send a request, I use SoapUI 5.5.

But **:body** is not null.

Do I need to do something in the settings of ORDS?

```
DECLARE
    --b_body BLOB := :body;
    c_body CLOB := :body_text;
BEGIN
    if :body_text is null then
    htp.print('EMPTY');
    end if; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/18.3/aelig/implicit-parameters.html#GUID-76A23568-EA67-4375-A4AA-880E1D160D27, for each implicit parameter :body and :body_text "*if it is dereferenced more than once, then the second and subsequent dereferences will appear to be empty.*"

So, change your code like this:

```
DECLARE
    --b_body BLOB := :body;
    c_body CLOB := :body_text;
BEGIN
    if c_body is null then
    htp.print('EMPTY');
    end if; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct it's not a good idea to use both binds in 1 code block...
If ORDS checks that you're using :body, :body_text is not populated (I think because of the overall performance of converting a blob to clob).

So just use :body_text and you should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

This symptom may result from creating RESTful Services via older versions of the APEX SQL Workshop interface. APEX 5.1 certainly exhibits this behaviour, possibly others. If you are unable to upgrade APEX, use SQL Developer to create your ORDS modules.